# How can I play song repeatedly using pygame.mixer.music.play()?

Tags: python, pygame

I have tried to repeat a song(mp3) using pygame module. The code is as follows from the site https://www.studytonight.com/tkinter/music-player-application-using-tkinter
When calling this function, it comes out only one time, of course it's natural.

```
    def playsong(self):      
       # Displaying Selected Song title
       self.track.set(self.playlist.get(ACTIVE))
       # Displaying Status
       self.status.set("-Playing")
       # Loading Selected Song
       pygame.mixer.music.load(self.playlist.get(ACTIVE))
       # Playing Selected Song
       pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

To repeat this sound file I added loop like this, but it plays just one time.
How can I repeat many times over and over this? Should I call the  function playsound(self) many times I want to repeat?

```
   def playsong(self):
    for i in range(3):
        # Displaying Selected Song title
        self.track.set(self.playlist.get(ACTIVE))
        # Displaying Status
        self.status.set("-Playing")
        # Loading Selected Song
        pygame.mixer.music.load(self.playlist.get(ACTIVE))
        # Playing Selected Song
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first optional argument (*loops*) to `pygame.mixer.music.play()` tells the function how often to repeate the music.

For instance pass 1 to play the music twice (repeat once):

```py
pygame.mixer.music.play(1)
```

Pass -1 to play the music infinitely:

```py
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
```

See [`pygame.mixer.music.play()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.play):

> `play(loops=0, start=0.0, fade_ms = 0) -> None`
>
> This will play the loaded music stream. If the music is already playing it will be restarted.
>
> ***loops* is an optional integer argument, which is 0 by default, it tells how many times to repeat the music. The music repeats indefinately if this argument is set to -1.**

Comment: Thanks so much. It works well. keep going forward thanks to you.